# Use two UIPickerView in the same UIView the second UIPickerView can not align center the content

Tags: swift

I use two UIPickerView in the same view, but the second one can not align center the content, can anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: Note: anything of the two pickerview are the same

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

When using two dynamic arrays of two UIPicker, this will happen.

So, Just be careful.